# How to add JSONArrayRequest without the use of for loop?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am using volley library and I want to pass data from a JSON API url with the GET method. What exactly I need is to get the user `ID == CurrentUserId`. Here is my full code:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, JSON_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject usersObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Name: "+usersObject, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    String ID = usersObject.getString("ID");
                    if (ID.equalsIgnoreCase(CurrentUser)) {
                        String fullName = usersObject.getString("fullName");
                        String userName = usersObject.getString("username");

                        fullname.setText(fullName);
                        username.setText(userName);
                    } else {
                        fullname.setText("No Name");
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Name: "+CurrentUser, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Name: "+ID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("CATCH", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });


        queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

The downside is that when I use the for loop the code continues to read every item of the JSON. On the other hand when I don't use the for loop I have to set an array index here `JSONObject usersObject = response.getJSONObject(i);`. So, what index should I set in order to make the code read every item and stop to what is ID == CurrentUserId?

Comment: but, you can break loop with `break;` statement when  `if(ID == CurrentUserId) break;` or you can continue looping with `continue;` statement when  `if(ID == CurrentUserId) continue;`.

Comment: @EAS Nice!! Thank you very much, you solved my problem!

Comment: Glad to hear this!